# Variables shadowing in Kotlin for inner classes: how variables are resolved?

Tags: java, kotlin, shadowing

I have the following code snippet in Kotlin. I love such code puzzlers, but the result here was too unexpected for me. Can someone describe me why it prints `1` and not `2`?

As shadowing is prohibited in Java - it looks like I completely do not understand how it works in Kotlin.

```
fun main() {
    var a = 1
    class A {
        var a = 2

        fun foo() = a
    }

    println(A().foo())
}
```

=========== BONUS ============

Funny thing is that the following code when you will move `var a = 1` after the class declaration works fine and prints `2`:

```
fun main() {
    
    class A {
        var a = 2

        fun foo() = a
    }

    var a = 1
    println(A().foo())
}
```

**UPD**: it looks like Kotlin suddenly decided to play like C++ and have undefined behavior :D

From the [Kotlin spec](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#implicit-this): `use this with caution, because in some cases it can be called instead`.

Comment: For the bonus I think you mean it prints `2`, not `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `var a = 2` inside the `class A`, **you're not actually shadowing any variable**. You're declaring that `a` is a **field** of class `A`, and it defaults to 2.

When you reference a variable in front of a class, Kotlin will add an implicit `this` (e.g. `a` becomes `this.a`) if there is a field with that name **but not an upper-level variable with that name**. So, the outer `a` takes precedence over the field, and you'd have to use `this.a` to access the inner `a`.

Comment: This was a little surprising to me. I'm trying to find where this behaviour is documented, but are unable to find it. Did you find find it written anywhere?

Comment: @marstran https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#implicit-this

Comment: Haha, I loved this phrase from a spec: "use this with caution, because in some cases it can be called instead". Very surprising and looks to be some kind of a gap in a spec :)